# jQuery DataTables - UK date column sorting

Tags: jquery, date, datatable, datatables

I'm using the DataTable plugin on one of my project - and the date-sorting is driving me crazy! ;)

Basically, I have tables with various number of columns (between 2 and 8 columns).
The date column is always the first column - **I want to set UK date format sorting on first column without knowing the exact number of columns.**

According to the doc here: **http://datatables.net/usage/columns**
the following 2 examples should work identical:

Example #1.  (**live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/yM24R/33/**)

```
       "aoColumnDefs": {
            "aTargets": [0] ,
            "sType": "uk_date"
        }
```

Example #2. (**live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/yM24R/**) - but with this way you must know the exact number of columns.

```
      "aoColumns": [
           {
            "sType": "uk_date"},
            null,
            null,
            null

            ]
```

**As you can see the second example works fine and sort the dates correctly, but the first one does not work at all.**

Have anyone of you have some experience with the plugin or the problem? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mixed up curly brackets with `[` `]`

```
"aoColumnDefs" : [
   {"aTargets" : [0] , "sType" : "uk_date"}
]
```

Comment: Great eye for details! Thanks. BTW, have you seen any more documentation about `aoColumnDefs` usage? For example how select `aTargets` with  a CSS Class?

Comment: It's all in the docs ;) Have a look at `sClass` - http://datatables.net/usage/columns#sClass

Comment: BTW, I have notices when date in `a href` the sorting does not work at all. Any solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

if the column is 3 then in order array mention 2

```
"order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]
```